# Программно задать ориентацию

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.
Возможно ли программно задать ориентацию фрагменту. То есть если телефон то ориентация меняется, если планшет то ориентация только горизонтально и неизменна.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[`Activity.setRequestedOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)).